# How to create specified distance between the end of a line and the baseline of the second line using css

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario where I should use specified distance between the end of the first line and the baseline/end of the second line in a paragraph element using css. Could someone suggest me the best way to achieve it.

The below image mention the same.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin-bottom` on `<p>` tags that equals to desired space minus line-height.

I am not sure if you can run dynamic calculations, but since you asked for a precise `43px` spacing, it seems to be `23px` assuming the `font-size` is `16px` while `line-height` is `20px`

> 43 - 20 = 23

**Here is a basic demo:**

```css
p {
  /* reset all spacing */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* assume the following font settings */
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  /* apply bottom margin */
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

/* optional: remove margin from last p tag */
p:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* just for demonstration */
p:nth-of-type(1):after {
  content:'';
  height:43px;
  width:3px;
  background:hotpink;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-38px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod porro quidem quae perferendis amet fuga id eveniet totam quis sapiente, in tempora commodi eaque, error doloremque neque adipisci! Enim, eos.</p>

<p>Maxime, dicta. Voluptatum quaerat, repellendus tempore veritatis vero voluptate inventore animi doloribus optio nulla non quisquam aperiam ratione labore quasi beatae doloremque. Tenetur possimus nisi minus, sed asperiores unde natus.</p>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/8u4n5n5y/

I'm guessing JavaScript would be required for a dynamic solution. Otherwise, hard code each value by declaring classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close by setting the `line-height` equal to the `font-size`.

For instance:

```
<style>
  p {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>

<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
```

In this case, you now know there is `12px` between the bottom of each element, so you can add a bottom margin to the first and that number plus the 12 will be your distance.

Comment: The OP meant spacing between two paragraphs not line-height of each sentence.

Comment: @Aziz I have two paragraphs. In fact, it seems very similar to the approach in your own answer. Please explain what you mean

Comment: There is no distance between them - https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/kf411bxz/ OP wants a distance of 43px

Comment: @Aziz Read my last paragraph

Comment: What do you mean? Test your solution with more text lines you will see how it doesn't work. And still where is the distance? You only have a line-height of 12px.

Comment: @Aziz Did you read it? It says "add a bottom margin to the first and that number plus 12 will be your distance". So if we apply that logic, we get 31 in this case. Here is the real example (I've also applied your line): https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/kf411bxz/

Comment: @Aziz Which brings me to the problem with your answer. Notice you have a magic number (-38) to position your pink line. In mine it's -43 (the distance), as it should be. The line height throws yours off.

Comment: Forgot to update the fiddle above, here's the correct one: https://jsfiddle.net/kf411bxz/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109242/discussion-between-aziz-and-aw04).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand u just need to put

```
line-height: 43px;
```

Comment: I am sorry I need 43px from the last line of first paragraph to the first line (from baseline) of second paragraph. However, each paragraph has its own line-height.

Comment: in this case add to the p a margin-bottom;
p { margin-bottom: 43px; }
but this will make a space of 43px + font-size; so you could make the margin a bit less, for example 31px if your font-size is 12. 
and if you want this to be the case only for a specific paragraph then add a class and use the class rather than the p

Comment: @MostafaFateen Line height rather than font size